# MYSQL Trigger only updates after ran twice at least

Tags: mysql, sql

My problem is, that i have trigger which works. I have 2 tables:

- node
- tableb

the query inside the trigger works, so i think i messed up the trigger, and i dont know what i did wrong (never used MySQL before so its a guessing game for me)

whenever i drop tableb and node table, and insert into node, the new value wont be counted into tableb, only if i insert into node once more. then everything works fine. My MySQL trigger is as follows:

```
DELIMITER //
  CREATE TRIGGER INSERT_USERS_FORUM 
  AFTER INSERT ON node
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

update tableb
set forum_count =  (select count(*) from node n, forum_index fi
     where n.nid = fi.nid   and fi.tid = 18
     and n.uid = new.uid
     group by n.uid)
where UID = new.uid;
END//
```

any helps is appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: If you have no rows in tableb, you can't update the record. If you do an insert update on duplicate key, that would ensure that a row exists in tableb for the uid. You would need either a primary key or unique key on uid in tableb

Comment: in tableb, there are records(ID,uid,forum_count), and if they have no record in node which fullfills the conditions in trigger, ther forum_count is 0

Comment: Maybe, but the update will fail because there is no record to be updated.

Comment: maybe i dont understand it well. it has an uid in tableb which should updated

Comment: In your question, you said _"whenever i drop tableb and node table, and insert into node"_ After you drop the tableb, it won't have any records.

Comment: maybe i should put a branch into the trgger where it checks if exists, if not it inserts, else the update?

Comment: i messed up the question, i meant empty the table with delete from tableb, node

Comment: As I mentioned before, use INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. That will attempt to insert a new row in tableb, and if a duplicate key exists, it will then update that record.

Comment: Same thing. If tableb is empty, the update will fail.

Comment: oh wow, thanks, sorry for me being this messy and not understanding you first. i just arrived home and been able to modify the trigger. it works now like a charm. would you please add this as an answer, so i can mark it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting a unique key on uid in tableb, and using INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, you can ensure that a row
exists in tableb to hold the forum count.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER INSERT_USERS_FORUM 
AFTER INSERT ON node
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `tableb`
    (`forum_count`)
    VALUES
    ((select count(*) from `node` n, `forum_index` fi
         where n.nid = fi.nid   and fi.tid = 18
         and n.uid = new.uid
         group by n.uid))
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `forum_count` =  (select count(*) from `node` n, `forum_index` fi
         where n.nid = fi.nid   and fi.tid = 18
         and n.uid = new.uid
         group by n.uid)
    where `UID` = new.`uid`;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You may already know this, but in case not...
 [`VALUES(one_column_name)` is also a magical function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values) in `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` queries that allows you to pluck a value you were going to insert, and reuse it for the update: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE forum_count = VALUES(forum_count)` (rather than repeat the entire subquery).